# Copy code whilst preserving syntax highlighting in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I am using Visual Studio Code and want to copy code from it, but I want to preserve the syntax highlighting.

I want something like "Copy as HTML" , "Copy as HTML with syntax and background intact" or the like. What extensions or plugins do I need to use to get this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible, you can +1 the issue to help prioritize it https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3518